# Chain-complex and Co-chain-complex valued Topological Quantum field theories

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

My research has led to me considering chain-complex and co-chain-complex valued topological quantum field theories. However, I am unable to find any literature that extensively studies this. *Is there any such piece on chain-complex and co-chain-complex valued topological quantum field theories?* If not, then could the community here provide a brief introduction to the same?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the MathOverflow format in inadequate for asking for a technical introduction to any kind of topological quantum field theories, or most subjects for that matter.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Where can I ask for the technical introduction?

Comment: Dear @Sanath Devalapurkar, I am afraid I cannot help you there, as you would be asking someone to write a short expository article for you. Concerning this question on MathOverflow, I think you will be more successful focussing on the reference request. If that fails, you can always try asking *specific* questions about the subject.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Thanks for the advice. I have edited my question.